# How do I get CreateObjectOptions by datacenter

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using URL `https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getCreateObjectOptions` and `https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions` to get hardware and virtual create object options.   How do I get the create Object Options by datacenter?

Answer (score 0):

there is no method for that, besides all the options that you are getting using the getCreateObjectOptions method should work on any datacenter.

Comment: Not really.   The AC* flavor is for vGPU which is supported only in DAL13.  How does the SoftLayer UI gather the proper Create Objects after a datacenter is selected?

Comment: because softlayer UI does not use the getCreateObjectOptions or the createObject method to create the servers, it uses the https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getRegions/ https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getActivePresets/ https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getActivePackages and many other methods  here you can see some explanation about those methods https://softlayer.github.io/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-3/

Comment: Thank you for the explanation